Apache Kafka consumer not being able to read all messages produced by multiple instances of Kafka consumer
My team has built a log storing mechanism which uses Kafka to store logs in the queue and store it in the database after consumer receives it.
The producer is running on an EC2 instance which is managed by a load balancer, and the consumer is on another instance writing into a database.
Mechanism of sending messages when instance of producer exists
When the traffic increases, multiple producers instances start with the same configuration as existing producer instance which sends data/messages to the pre-existing consumer EC2 instance, where the set condition for the spawning instances is to spawn in the same region but based on availability of zones.
Multiple producer instances sending data to consumer
The problem is when a lot of producer instances are running, there is loss of data in logs, where the consumer is not receiving the messages in the queue.
Pre-conditions have been set such that security group ids match and external ip of consumer instance is provided, so connecting to consumer should not be an issue.
All possible conditions for the instances have been tried.
Not all the logs are going missing but around 15-20% of the total count. Trying to figure out where the issue might be, could it because of AWS or Kafka?
This is the producer code in golang:
func pushLogToKafka(str string, flg bool) {

    var logEntry MongoLogInfoType
    logEntry.Message = str
    logEntry.Timestamp, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
    logEntry.Flag = flg
    jsonString, err := json.Marshal(logEntry)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    logString := string(jsonString)

    var producer *kafka.Producer = kafkaInit.Producer

    // Produce messages to topic (asynchronously)
    topic := config.ApiLogTopic
    for _, word := range []string{string(logString)} {
        producer.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
            Value:          []byte(word),
        }, nil)
    }
} 

This is the consumer code:
func Listen() {
    log.Println("Consuming from kafka topics")
    c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers":                  config.BootstrapServers,
        "group.id":                           config.GroupId,
        "auto.offset.reset":                  config.AutoOffsetReset,
        "topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms": config.TopicMetadataRefresh,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        logs := "Kafka consumer failed \n" + err.Error()
        writeLogFile(config.LogsFilePath, []byte(logs))
    }
    c.SubscribeTopics([]string{config.ApiLogTopic, config.SendSmsTopic}, nil)

    for {
        msg, err := c.ReadMessage(-1)
        if err == nil {
            logString := string(msg.Value)
            var kafkaLog core.LogInfo
            b := []byte(logString)
            err := json.Unmarshal(b, &kafkaLog)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err.Error())
            }
         }
}

Thank you for your assistance in the following matter.

Of the top of my head, I would say it is the queue config or the subscription settings. I'd strongly suggest to activate explicit acknowledgement of messages and use transactions for the database (with retry, if possible) and only acknowledge the messages when the transaction was successful. Also, please provide a [mre]. Otherwise, this question cannot be answered in any meaningful way.

Sorry, I did not explain the above correctly: The ack policy must be set on the producer side (and probably should be set to all or leader).

Sorry for the delayed response, I have edited and added the code, but the problem might be that one of the spawned EC2 instances due to overloading, is not even sending data to the kafka queue. Thank you for your assistance once again.

Wanted to implement an async mechanism, which keeps receiving data at high volume and high rate, as a result didn't want to implement explicit acknowledgement which would just increase latency. Could there be any specific network configurations which needs to be set in aws?

Do you actually have performance issues? Because if not, remember what Donald Knuth said: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."
